# Selenium not opening firefox with geckodriver 10.0 - unreachable browser exception

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, geckodriver

I am having some difficulties with Selenium opening Firefox.  It works on my computer at home but I am not sure why it doesnt work on my work computer.  Some help and guidance on this would be much appreciated because I am newbie to this tool and eclipse.

I have downloaded geckodriver 10 and am running Selenium 3 with Eclipse Neon.  I imported the selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3 to the Java Build Path to my test Selenium project.

My code is as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class openBrowser {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\JW\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");


}

}
```

When I run the program I get the following in the console:

```
Sep 30, 2016 10:42:18 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
```

INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.0.0-beta3', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:57:03 -0700'
System info: host: 'SBC-40489825', ip: '10.27.20.46', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_73'

I run the program but firefox never seems to open as the connection seems to be refused Any ideas whats wrong?

Best Regards

Tarquin

Answer (score 1):

Try Marrionatedriver, it will use. Following is the code:

```
WebDriver driver = new MarrionateDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you don't use `beta` version until a final stable version of [`Selenium3`](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/the-road-to-selenium-3/) is not being released **there may have many bugs which would be fix.**

You should downgrade your selenium version to last stable version of [`Selenium2`](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/).

Because `Selenium2` works well without using `GeckoDriver` to lunch [Mozilla Firefox < v47](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/), you should downgrade it as well below `v47` to get rid from these issues until final version of [`Selenium3`](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/the-road-to-selenium-3/) is not being released.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is specific to Geckodriver Windows32 bit.

GeckoDriver doesn't support Windows 32Bit, they are yet to release Geckodriver V0.11 version. You check version [Milestone status](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/milestone/1)

You can also check the discussion on this issue [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/pull/213) last comments

Here is an [article](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3) that explains this issue.

**UPDATE : Geckodriver V0.11 version released. Please try use this version.**

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",D:\\JW\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe);
```